# Office Excel average function: what's the difference between AVERAGE(A2:C2 B1:B10) and AVERAGE(A2:C2, B1:B10)?

Tags: excel, arguments, average, space

From Office Excel `AVERAGE` function examples, the argument always use comma as the delimiter.  However, `AVERAGE(A2:C2 B1:B10)` is also valid in Excel.

My question:  what is the difference and why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space would be the intersect operator, returning only those cells that are included in both ranges, whereas the comma will create a union of both ranges.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In fact, it's true. But I didn't find any example or clue from Microsoft website or Excel help document mentioned about the space would be the intersect operator. Could you please share with me where did you get this answer, thanks.

Comment: Trial and error :) - Googleing *excel formula intersect* confirmed my findings, but I haven't found anything official either, why I didn't include any links.

Comment: Thanks for your help answer!!

Comment: If this answer helps you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left. That will indicate to others that this answer was helpful to you and will also generate reputation points for both of us. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: [Intersect Operator](https://trumpexcel.com/intersect-operator-in-excel/) explain about it